# Use method without downcasting

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a method for convert different classes

```
protected Object convert(String body,Util util) {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(body);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if(util instanceof MyUtil) {
            // returning a myClass object
            return objectMapper.readValue(reader, myClass.class);
        }
        throw new RuntimeError("Class to converter not exist");
    }
```

then I am using this method and casting to MyClass

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass) converter.convert(util);
```

how would it look for only one class

```
protected MyClass convert(String body,Util util) {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(body);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(reader, MyClass.class);
    }
```

```
MyClass myclass = converter.convert(util);
```

Is possible to refactor method to make it more flexible to different return classes and avoid casting?

Comment: Since you removed important information from you code it is not answerable. So you can start be fixing your posted `convert` method and then you can explain why you explicitly return `Object`.

Comment: @Tom I added more information in method body, but I dont think it makes more understandable. So my flow it to make my code more flexible, right now I have class hierarchy to convert from json and checking what exactly an implementation. When someone would add more implementation he could add one more if statement to check which one util and provide his hierarchy of classes to convert.
If I back to only one implementation I could change to exactly only one type(not an object).

Comment: *"but I dont think it makes more understandable"* ... correct, you still have `return;` there, that is neither valid syntax nor helpful in any case. This makes the whole question unanswerable.

Comment: @Tom sorry. changed statement

Comment: Ok, this makes it much clearer. When you have something "weird" there, like `return new Object();`, then an approach like in the below answer wouldn't be possible. This is why it is important to know such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the signature to match what `readValue` is doing.

```java
protected <T> T convert(String body, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new StringReader(body);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.readValue(reader, clazz);
}
```

```java
MyClass myclass = app.convert(json, MyClass.class);
```

This can of course still lead to all kind of exceptions if the input does not match the expected class.

Comment: Actually what I needed, thank you. One more question, if I am reusing this method in another method and trying to return class and I dont know which one class will be. Something like `public Object getMessages(){
return converter.convert(json, MyClass.class);
}` , but if I provide Object it back me to downcasting. is anyway to provide generic to make it as you provided example?

Comment: @Max You can use the same approach for `getMessages()` as well, so you need a parameter and a correct return type. Your return type `Object` is the issue here, use `T`, like in the answer.